# Finding a bound on the difference of two functions

Tags: real-analysis

What is this asking? I am going through a textbook and don't understand the problem

Find a bound on the difference of $\sin x$ and  $x-\frac{x^3}{6}+\frac{x^5}{120}$ for $x \in [0,1]$

Comment: It means you have to find a constant $C$ such that $|\sin x -(x-x^3/6+x^5/120)|\le C$ on $x\in[0,1]$. However, the smaller your $C$ is, the better.

Comment: This file is useful: http://www.math.wisc.edu/~ross/teaching/201009-222/remainders.pdf

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**.  The problem means, find a constant $M$ such that
$$\left|\sin x-\left(x-\frac{x^3}{6}+\frac{x^5}{120}\right)\right|\le M$$
for all $x\in[0,1]$.  You should recognise the second expression as the degree $5$ Taylor polynomial for $\sin x$ in powers of $x$.  We can write an equality with a remainder term,
$$\sin x=x-\frac{x^3}{6}+\frac{x^5}{120}+R_5(x)\ .$$
The difference is $R_5(x)$, and I'm sure your textbook will have theorems for finding bounds on this quantity - look up something like "Taylor series with remainder" in the index.

Read your text carefully, see what you can find, and try to finish the problem.

**Comments**

- A "sneaky trick": your expression can also be viewed as the degree $6$ Taylor polynomial,
  $$\sin x=x-\frac{x^3}{6}+\frac{x^5}{120}+0x^6+R_6(x)\ ,$$
  and this may give you a better bound than the above.
- Some books use a slightly different notation: they might have $R_6$ where I have written $R_5$ and $R_7$ where I have written $R_6$.  Check your textbook carefully.